# error the method toarray() is undefined for the type collection___

Tags: openjdk-11

A error in the list which is  "error the method toarray() is undefined for the type collection___", the error is in the openjdk11. using the jdk8 is all right.

debug the code, there is the error in the list.

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Maybe it should display the parameters in the debug moden.